# Métodos con un solo parámetro que requiera más

Tags: c#

Me gustaría saber como puedo hacer un método que tenga un solo parámetro y que en base a este necesite más, me explico:

Necesito que, por ejemplo, si tienes esto:

```
public enum color{
 rojo,
 azul,
 verde
}
void foo(color _color){
 //si es color.rojo, necesito un int
 //si es color.azul, necesito un string
 //si es color.azul, necesito un bool
}
```

Al llamar a foo con el parámetro color.rojo tendría que acompañarlo con un int:

`foo(color.rojo, 1);`

Al llamar a foo con el parámetro color.azul tendría que acompañarlo con un string:

`foo(color.azul, "hola");`

Y por último si tuviese que llamar a foo con el parámetro color.verde tendría que acompañarlo con un bool:

`foo(color.verde, true);`

Se que podría hacerlo creando el método `foo(color _color, int a = 0, string b = "", bool c = false)` pero si en vez de haber 3 colores hay 10, la cosa se pone difícil.

¿Qué me recomendáis que haga? ¿Cuál es la mejor opción para manejar este tipo de situaciones?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El parámetro puede ser de tipo `object` y en el método según el caso hacer un casting:

```
void foo(color _color, object parametro){
     //si es tipo.rojo, hacer casting a int: int param = (int) parametro;
     //si es tipo.azul, hacer casting a string: string param = (string) parametro;
     //si es tipo.azul, hacer casting a bool: bool param = (bool) parametro;
    }
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, era exactamente lo que estaba buscando.